# lightning:fileCard not updating description

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using a lightning fileCard to display on a lightning card to show status on an uploaded file. When I upload a file, the image preview and the description are accurate. However, when I re-upload another image.. the image get's updated but the description is stuck as the old one. When I log the v.filename attribute the value is correct so that isn't the issue.

CMP:

```
           <lightning:card title="Upload a New File" class="slds-p-top_medium">
               <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-p-bottom_medium">
               <lightning:fileUpload  name="fileUploader"
                                     label= "Upload File"
                                     multiple="{! false }"
                                     accept="{! v.accept }"
                                     recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                                     onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }"
                                     />
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.documentId != ''}">
                    <br />
                    <lightning:fileCard aura:id="fileCard" fileId="{! v.documentId}" description="{! v.fileName}" />
                    {! v.fileName}
                </aura:if>
               </div>
           </lightning:card>
```

CTRLR:

```
handleUploadFinished : function (cmp, evt) {
    var uploadedFiles = evt.getParam("files");
    var fileDocumentId = uploadedFiles[0].documentId;

    var action = cmp.get("c.getFilename");

    action.setParams({ documentId : fileDocumentId,
                        recordId : cmp.get("v.recordId")});

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set("v.fileName", response.getReturnValue());
            cmp.set("v.documentId", fileDocumentId);
            cmp.set("v.continueDisabled", false);
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    this.displayError(cmp, response.getError());
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Answer (score 2):

For reason unknown, the only way I got the `description` to be updated was by forcing the `documentId` to a blank value so that the block within `aura:if` re-renders. And that worked. I failed to understand why would the `fileId` get updated but not `description`.

So where you are setting the value of `documentId`, I introduced another `cmp.set` to se the value to empty string, and it worked.

```
cmp.set("v.documentId", ''); // forcefully set it to blank value to re-render aura:if
cmp.set("v.documentId", fileDocumentId); // now set to actual value to re-render aura:if again
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution, but a few work arounds are:

1. Dynamically create the component in the handleUploadFinished method from above
2. Disable the description on the file card and instead render the title separately

I chose the 2nd solution:

```
<lightning:fileCard fileId="{! v.documentId}" hideDescription="true" />
    <br />
<lightning:formattedText value="{! 'Filename: ' + v.fileName}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this instead and let me know if this fixes your problem

```
<lightning:card title="Upload a New File" class="slds-p-top_medium">
           <div class="slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-p-bottom_medium">
           <lightning:fileUpload name="fileUploader"
                                 label= "Upload File"
                                 multiple="{!false}"
                                 accept="{!v.accept}"
                                 recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                 onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}"
                                 />
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.documentId != ''}">
                <br/>
                <lightning:fileCard aura:id="fileCard" fileId="{!v.documentId}" description="{!v.fileName}"/>
                {!v.fileName}
            </aura:if>
           </div>
       </lightning:card>
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: When you're calling you're using this {! v.accept} which won't call, removing the space will allow the code to call.

Comment: Please include some description of the issue and your solution alongside the code paste. "Code dump" or "code only" answers tend to produce a lot of back and forth in comments and provide limited value to the community.

Comment: @HarrySmith if you're suggesting removing the space between ! and the attribute reference - that does not work.